# Swift enum associated value with different types

Tags: ios, swift, enums, swift5

I have a Swift enum like this:

```
public enum AnimationType {

    case position(Float)
    case position([Keyframe<Float>])
    case scale(Float)
    case scale([Keyframe<Float>])
    case rect(CGRect)
    case rect([Keyframe<CGRect>])
    case transform(CGAffineTransform)
    case transform([Keyframe<CGAffineTransform>])
    ...
    ...
}
```

As we can see, for each type there are two values possible - fixed value of type T or an array of keyframes with value type T ([Keyframe]). I am wondering if there is anything I can do to avoid repetition of same name in the enum and merge the two enum case types? Or I am modelling it wrong way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would solve this with a `Kind` enum type, for each kind of variation.

```
public enum AnimationType {
    public enum Kind<Value> {
        case scalar(Value)
        case keyframes([Keyframe<Value>])
    }

    case position(Kind<Float>)
    case scale(Kind<Float>)
    case rect(Kind<CGRect>)
    case transform(Kind<CGAffineTransform>)
}
```

Usage:

```
let anim1 = AnimationType.position(.scalar(10))
let anim2 = AnimationType.position(.keyframes([Keyframe(10)]))
```

Getting values:

```
switch anim1 {
case .position(let kind):
    switch kind {
    case .scalar(let value):
        print("value: \(value)")
    case .keyframes(let keyframes):
        print("keyframes: \(keyframes)")
    }

default: // You would implement the rest
    break
}
```

```
switch anim1 {
case .position(.scalar(let value)):
    print("value: \(value)")

case .position(.keyframes(let keyframes)):
    print("keyframes: \(keyframes)")

default: // You would implement the rest
    break
}
```

```
if case .position(.scalar(let value)) = anim1 {
    print("value: \(value)")
}
```

---

You can also add `Codable` conformance:

```
public struct Keyframe<Value: Codable> {
    let value: Value

    init(_ value: Value) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

extension Keyframe: Codable {
    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        try container.encode(value)
    }

    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        value = try container.decode(Value.self)
    }
}
```

```
public enum AnimationType {
    public enum Kind<Value: Codable> {
        case scalar(Value)
        case keyframes([Keyframe<Value>])
    }

    case position(Kind<Float>)
    case scale(Kind<Float>)
    case rect(Kind<CGRect>)
    case transform(Kind<CGAffineTransform>)
}

extension AnimationType.Kind: Codable {
    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()

        switch self {
        case .scalar(let value): try container.encode(value)
        case .keyframes(let keyframes): try container.encode(keyframes)
        }
    }

    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()

        if let scalar = try? container.decode(Value.self) {
            self = .scalar(scalar)
            return
        }
        if let keyframes = try? container.decode([Keyframe<Value>].self) {
            self = .keyframes(keyframes)
            return
        }

        // You should throw error here instead
        fatalError("Failed to decode")
    }
}

extension AnimationType: Codable {
    private enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case position
        case scale
        case rect
        case transform
    }

    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        switch self {
        case .position(let kind): try container.encode(kind, forKey: .position)
        case .scale(let kind): try container.encode(kind, forKey: .scale)
        case .rect(let kind): try container.encode(kind, forKey: .rect)
        case .transform(let kind): try container.encode(kind, forKey: .transform)
        }
    }

    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        if let position = try? container.decode(Kind<Float>.self, forKey: .position) {
            self = .position(position)
            return
        }
        if let scale = try? container.decode(Kind<Float>.self, forKey: .scale) {
            self = .scale(scale)
            return
        }
        if let rect = try? container.decode(Kind<CGRect>.self, forKey: .rect) {
            self = .rect(rect)
            return
        }
        if let transform = try? container.decode(Kind<CGAffineTransform>.self, forKey: .transform) {
            self = .transform(transform)
            return
        }

        // You should throw error here instead
        fatalError("Failed to decode")
    }
}
```

Example encoding:

```
do {
    let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(anim1)
    if let str = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
        print(str)
        // Prints: {"position":10}
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

The same sort of thing with `anim2` returns `{"position":[10]}`.

Comment: This is cool, but how do I test the type of parameter in code (whether it is scalar or keyframes)? Do I need to use switch statement everytime?

Comment: true. switch in switch

Comment: @DeepakSharma Updated my answer on how to get the values. You can also create a computed property on the `AnimationType` enum to read these values, if that makes it easier in your case.

Comment: @George This is good, now the next challenge is how to make this enum Kind<Value>  confirm to Codable given that Value is Codable. Because without this, I will need to reencode keyframes in every switch statement.

Comment: @DeepakSharma I've added the `Codable` conformance, but I'm going to improve the implementation because the default result isn't great

Comment: @DeepakSharma Improved the `Codable` conformance, take a look!

Comment: I looked at it, I am newbie to this Swift Codable/Decodable as I have been using NSCoding and dictionaries so far. I was using PropertyListEncoder/Decoder while you use JSON. Any reasons for using one over the other?

Comment: @DeepakSharma Codable is far better. When you encode the JSON, it turns directly into your `AnimationType` struct (not just a dictionary with the same keys). JSON is also a standard format, easier to use with various things such as APIs. I 100% recommend Codable & JSON over older methods like NSCoding. Codable is far easier, safer, and has better interoperability than any other method.

Comment: I think this enum with generic type is causing lot of coding pain for me. Everytime I need to modify the params, I need to use a big switch statement. And such switch statements now proliferate the code. Plus Swift enums are pass by value, but I see pass by reference is what I need. What is class based equivalent of the same enum?

Comment: @DeepakSharma Create some methods on the enum to read/write values. It all depends on how you use it, but you could move that duplicated `switch` code to just a method. In terms of passing by value vs reference - you don’t want to pass these by reference, since these are values. If you want to pass a collection of animations by reference for example, just create a class to contain them - e.g. `DrawingAnimation` containing some property like `animations`.

Comment: I am storing these values in a graph like datastructure. Each node in the graph stores the animation enum value. When i need to change some value, it becomes messy to find vertices in the graph storing the value and update it. With pass by reference, I avoid all this traversals of graph.

Comment: @DeepakSharma It’s worth creating a [mre] and posting a new question about it

Comment: @George Does this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70293048/converting-swift-enum-to-class) works for you ?

Answer (score 1):

@George's answer did solve this.

Swift's solution is of variety.

Here is my proposal:

```
public struct Keyframe<T> {
    let v : T
}

public enum AnimaKind{
    case simple
    case series
}

public enum AnimatationType {
    case position
    case scale
    case rect
    case transform
}

extension AnimatationType{
    
    func simple<T>(info: T) -> (type: AnimatationType, kind: AnimaKind, info: T){
        return (self, .simple, info)
    }
    
    func series<T>(info: [T]) -> (type: AnimatationType, kind: AnimaKind, info: [Keyframe<T>]){
        let result = info.map { x in Keyframe(v: x) }
        return (self, .series, result)
    }
}
```

as you can see, the way you unwrap is easier

```
func test(){
    let animaTest = AnimatationType.position.simple(info: Float(10))
}
```

you get value from `animaTest` is convenient,

`tuple` vs `enum nested`

Comment: How do I identify the type of parameter in a given AnimatationType object using this code (whether simple or series)?

Comment: `(type: AnimatationType, kind: AnimaKind, info: [Keyframe<T>])` :  AnimatationType you want,  simple scalar or series [Frame], simple scalar value or series [Frame] values     .   you can use it directly

Answer (score 1):

I assume that at the lower end you are using some common code to exploit the two types, so you can benefit polymorphism by grouping them under some protocol:

```swift
public enum AnimatationType {
    case position(PositionProtocol)
    case scale(ScaleProtocol)
    case rect(RectProtocol)
    case transform(TransformProtocol)
    ...
    ...
}
```

And simply extend the types:

```swift
extension Float: PositionProtocol {
     func someCommonGround() -> SomeCommonType { ... }
}

extension Keyframe: PositionProtocol where KeyframeGenericArgument == Float {
     func someCommonGround() -> SomeCommonType { ... }
}
```