# Converting Swift enum to Class

Tags: ios, swift, enums

I have the following code to implement animation models based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69036422/swift-enum-associated-value-with-different-types) answer:

```
 public enum AnimationType {
   public enum Kind<Value> {
      case scalar(Value)
      case keyframes([Keyframe<Value>])
   }

    case position(Kind<Float>)
    case scale(Kind<Float>)
    case rect(Kind<CGRect>)
    case transform(Kind<CGAffineTransform>)
    ....
    ....
  }

  public class Keyframe<T> : Codable, Comparable where T:Codable, T:Interpolatable  {
      public var time:CMTime
      public var property:String
      public var value:T
      ...
      ...
  }
```

This data model was chosen as I found it type safe for each animation property as it couples data type with the property (for instance, value for property transform can only be CGAffineTransform, the code wouldn't accept anything else). But now I face two troubles:

1. Directly fetching property value or modifying keyframes is not so easy, one needs to write a big switch statement everytime or atleast  *if case let* statement to fetch the property, which makes code look messy if done at hundreds of places,
2. Most important, Swift enums are pass by value but I realize I need pass by reference or class based implementation. This is because it would be much easier to modify the underlying object parameters in case of pass by reference. In case of pass by value such as enum, I need to again create new values and pass them to the animation code (which has it's own data model for rendering animation). Reconstructing or updating data structures for animation rendering is a pain and can be avoided with class.

However, I am not sure if there is such a type safe approach to convert such an enum to class, or make enum pass by reference for that matter. Any inputs are welcome.

Comment: You can do simulate pass-by-reference using `inout`. Is that enough? And what sort of solution are you looking for for 1? "Type safe" implies that you are forced to add checks, so that it is safe. You'd have to completely change your design otherwise.

Comment: How do I use inout to solve it? Let's say I have an animation graph data structure to perform animation and some vertices in the graph store animation type & value (enum). To perform updates, I will need to find the vertices in the graph storing this enum type, and update it with new value. If it was just pass by reference, it is much easier. No graph traversal required.

Comment: @DeepakSharma Can you provide an example of the old code for part 1 of the question? Because these `AnimationType`s have different values, therefore different data types, so I'm not sure how you expect to set a value without checking it's for the correct case.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep using enums I think you can make issue 1 a bit easier to deal with if you add an optional property for each associated value in the enum cases.
Something like:

```swift
public enum AnimationType {
  public enum Kind<Value> {
    case scalar(Value)
    case keyframes([Keyframe<Value>])

    var scalar: Value? {
      guard case let .scalar(value) = self else { return nil }
      return value
    }

    var keyframes: [Keyframe<Value>]? {
      guard case let .keyframes(keyframes) = self else { return nil }
      return keyframes
    }
  }

  case position(Kind<Float>)
  case scale(Kind<Float>)
  case rect(Kind<CGRect>)
  case transform(Kind<CGAffineTransform>)

  var position: Kind<Float>? {
    guard case let .position(kind) = self else { return nil }
    return kind
  }

  var transform: Kind<CGAffineTransform>? {
    guard case let .transform(kind) = self else { return nil }
    return kind
  }

}
```

With this you won't need to have the big `switch` you are mentioning because you directly try to get the associated value you need.
You can also have a look at [swift-case-paths](https://github.com/pointfreeco/swift-case-paths) which basically adds Keypath support to enum with associated values and removes the need to add this vars boilerplate.

Comment: That solves one part of the problem, how about enum pass by reference? I need pass by reference for ease. How to do that?

Comment: And how to mutate these associated values? The vars you define are only getters. I would also want to mutate position, transform etc.